Check broken links with wget on all pages recursively, not on the first page encountered only
I want to find broken links on entire domains using wget.
I tried the following options:
wget -r -nv --spider https://fr.ewen.works --span-hosts --domains=fr.ewen.works,en.ewen.works

Unfortunately, it only seems to find broken links that appear on / of the given domains.
wget only finds three "broken" links[^1], and they all appear on /. I tried to introduce a broken link on another page, and it's absent
[^1]: Those are false positives because I guess some websites disallow crawlers. I process exceptions in my script that calls wget, but that's a separate issue anyways
I tried searching online but all tutorials and blog articles talk about checking for broken links on a single page.
I also tried removing the --spider option so that it has an opportunity to check the contents of the crawled pages, but the output is more difficult to parse (the "Found n broken links" output is no longer there) and more importantly the broken links are still not found.
Is it possible to instruct wget to search for broken links on all crawled pages of the given --domains?
